# Upload two files using two input files with PHP

Tags: php

I have an HTML5 form which aims to request the photo and the CV of visitors with two different input files (I don't want a single input file for the two files).

the form works well with a single input file of the CV or of the photo with the following code:

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<form action="upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  Select file to upload:
  <input type="file" name="CV" id="CV">
  <input type="submit" value="Upload Image" name="submit">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

**upload.php**

```
<?php
$target_dir = "uploads/";
$CV_target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["CV"]["name"]);
$CVFileType = strtolower(pathinfo($CV_target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION));
move_uploaded_file($_FILES["CV"]["tmp_name"], $CV_target_file)
?>
```

My problem is that once there are two input files, I can't load the files.
Then the code of the **index.html** file becomes:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<form action="upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  Select file to upload:
  <input type="file" name="CV" id="CV">
  <input type="file" name="PHOTO" id="PHOTO">
  <input type="submit" value="Upload Image" name="submit">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

the PHP code I tried for two input files:

```
    <?php
    $target_dir = "uploads/";
    $CV_target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["CV"]["name"]);
    $PHOTO_target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["PHOTO"]["name"]);
    $CVFileType = strtolower(pathinfo($CV_target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION));
    $PHOTOFileType = strtolower(pathinfo($PHOTO_target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION));
    move_uploaded_file($_FILES["CV"]["tmp_name"], $CV_target_file);
    move_uploaded_file($_FILES["PHOTO"]["tmp_name"], $PHOTO_target_file);
?>
```

But I can't find the correct PHP code.
do you have any suggestions for me?
Thank you so much.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/219982/discussion-on-question-by-mehdi-saoudi-upload-two-files-using-two-input-files-wi).

Answer (score 0):

A file upload field that accepts multiple values

```
<input type="file"  name="files" multiple>
```

Comment: OP says: "`(I don't want a single input file for the two files).`"

Comment: @Martin exactly, I want two input files not a single multiple

Answer (score 0):

Just looking at your PHP code:

```
<?php
$target_dir = "uploads/";
$CV_target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["CV"]["name"]);
$PHOTO_target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["PHTO"]["name"]);
                                                  // typo above?
$imageFileType = strtolower(pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION));
                                  // $target_file variable does not exist
move_uploaded_file($_FILES["CV"]["tmp_name"], $Bac_target_file)
                                           // $Bac_target_file does not exist
move_uploaded_file($_FILES["PHOTO"]["tmp_name"], $Bac_target_file)
                                                   // also these last two lines are
                                                   // lacking semicolons
?>
```

Perhaps, try this:

```
<?php
    $target_dir = "uploads/";
    $CV_target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["CV"]["name"]);
    $PHOTO_target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["PHOTO"]["name"]);
    $imageFileType = strtolower(pathinfo($PHOTO_target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION));
    move_uploaded_file($_FILES["CV"]["tmp_name"], $CV_target_file);
    move_uploaded_file($_FILES["PHOTO"]["tmp_name"], $PHOTO_target_file);
?>
```

Comment: Can you explain the problem in detail please?  As far as I am aware the problem is that you "can't load both files" - if you could explain, step by step, exactly how to re-create the problem you are experiencing it would be easier to help you out.